# Optimise jQuery filter for unique elements

Tags: optimization, jquery, jquery-data, jquery-filter

I have a collection of elements, and whilst each *has* a unique String identifier, **I can't safely use it's value as the elements** `ID` **as I can't guarantee that it'll only contain [valid characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)**.  As a result, I'm storing the identifiers in each of the elements jQuery `.data()` object. Whilst I could use a `data-` attribute, I don't really like the idea of using selectors where I may have to escape quotes etc., but if there's a huge efficiency bonus, it should be taken into consideration. A solution using the `.data()` object would be also be great as this could be applicable for any data type.

I'm wondering what the most efficient way to select a single element would be. At present, this is my solution:

```
function get_group($from, group) {
  var $result = $();
  $from.each(function() {
    if($(this).data("group") == group) {
      result = $(this);
      return false;
    }
  });
  return $result;
}
```

I iterate over each of my results until I find a match. When I do, I break from the loop. By initializing `$result` as an empty jQuery object, I'll always *return jQuery*, which I think is most consistent with standard practice and in particular the `.filter()` method.

I think this is better than using `.filter()` with a function as it explicitly returns a single (or no) item, and stops iteration as soon as it needs to, but **is there a better approach?**

Comment: Do you create those element dynamically? Or do you have any control on their creation and appending to the page?

Comment: If your data does not include quotes (single or double) why not use a data-group attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that a `for` loop is faster than the one you've got:

```
function get_group ($from, group)
    for (var i = 0; i < $from.length; i++) {
        if ($($from[i]).data("group") == group) {
            return $($from[i]);
        }
    }
    return $();
}
```

JSPerf: http://jsperf.com/each-vs-data-selector

**EDIT: Rewrote to function, added return $()**

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using a HTML5 `data-` attribute, I'm using a jQuery `data()` object's attribute. However, looking at your tests, that seems like a pretty nice solution - do you really need to wrap the `$from[i]` in jQuery though? Also, you'd need to return `$()` if you completed the loop unsuccessfully.

Comment: Yeah, I know you're not. I added the tests because some of the answers suggest that that would be the fastest solution. As for wrapping `$from[i]` in jQuery, that is necessary, because `$from[i]` is not a jQuery object. I've added an example using `.eq(i)` instead, but that one's slower.

Comment: This was the best answer, sorry for taking so long to give it recognition.

Answer (score 0):

As you said , if each data-group is unique, you can do this -

```
$('[data-group="'+group+'"]')
```

Comment: I don't like this approach as appending an unknown string into a jQuery selector doesn't seem sensible (not least because of quote issues)

Answer (score 0):

```
$from.find('[data-group="' + group + '"]')
```

Comment: I don't like this approach as appending an unknown string into a jQuery selector doesn't seem sensible (not least because of quote issues)

Comment: Agreed, but this approach makes code compact and readable and jQuery has a failsafe mechanism that returns an empty array if the selector matches nothing. Problems will arise if the given sting corrupts the JS syntax. I guess the decision will depend on whether the actual text is supplied by a program (fairly safe) or a user (potentially unsafe).

Comment: Although elegant, it's almost 60% slower than making a simple for loop.

Comment: Performance vs code clarity trade-off. But question was 'Optimize' so +1 for Nicklas ;)